# ASP.NET MVC: How to render a different action (not view) with the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action

It's really easy to return a different View from the Controller:

```
return View("../Home/Info");
```

However, I need a model in the Info view. I have a lot of stuff going on in the Info() action result method. I can just copy it and have something like this:

```
var infoModel = new InfoModel {
    // ... a lot of copied code here
}
return View("../Home/Info", infoModel);
```

But that is not reasonable.

Of course I can just redirect:

```
return RedirecToAction("Info");
```

But this way the URL will change. I don't want to change the URL. That's very important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you want to invoke an action from a different controller.  I'd suggest that you might want to simply render a view that renders that action using [Html.Action()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728618.aspx) instead of trying to tie the two together in the controller.  If that's unreasonable then you might want to create a base controller that both controllers can derive from and put the shared code to generate the model in base controller.  Reuse the view as needed.

```
  public ActionResult Foo()
  {
      return View();
  }
```

Foo View

```
  @Html.Action( "info", "home" )
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a small not: @{ Html.RenderAction(...); } is better performance wise.

Comment: does exactly what I wanted, hadn't thought of this.

Answer (score 9):

You can call right to another action from within an action, like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(){
   if(somethingOrAnother){
      return MyOtherAction();
   }
   return View();
}

//"WhichEverViewYouNeed" is required here since you are returning this view from another action
//if you don't specify it, it would return the original action's view
public ActionResult MyOtherAction(){
    return View("WhichEverViewYouNeed", new InfoModel{...});
}
```

Comment: The view will correspond to the action that's invoked initially unless you specify which view you want explicitly.

Comment: @tvanfosson His question suggests he's already going to be specifying the view.

Comment: Yes, but in your example it will still look for the *MyAction* view even if *MyOtherAction* is called.  You'd need to do a `return View( "MyOtherAction", new InfoModel { ... } );` if you always wanted to render the view that goes along with it.

Comment: @tvanfosson Ahh, yes; I didn't realize I wasn't doing the same in my example. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Such an easy solution! Never thought about it. The only thing (and I'm sorry about forgetting to mention it) is that the other action is in a different controller. Can I just call new HomeController().MyOtherAction() ?

Comment: No, you can't (shouldn't) just do that. See tvanfosson's answer for the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just invoke the method of the action?

Comment: He says he doesn't want the URL to change. (My biggest disappointment with MVC is that it's caused people to become obsessed with urls, often pointlessly.) Probably a partial view would work here.

Comment: @Ryan Invoking a different action method, as in my answer, would *not* change the URL. And I don't think it was MVC at all that got people obsessed with not changing URLs; do a search for Server.Transfer and see lots of WebForms obsession, too.